# Can one push a wild animal using the Handle Animal skill?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, animals

I was wondering how the *Handle Animal* skill can be used when concerning wild animals.  For example;

If you come across a wolf in the woods and he's hungry and eyeing you down like he wants to attack, could you *push* the wolf with the *down* trick to make it back down and walk away?

Could you generally *push* wild animals to perform tricks in this fashion?

Comment: Your scenario would be a time when you might want to use the class feature wild empathy that Druids and Rangers have. Or the diplomacy/intimidate skill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No, Although Only by Implication

I really wanted this to be *Yes* because the fallout from that *Yes* would be huge. Unfortunately, the [Handle Animal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/handle-animal) skill says in the section Untrained

> If you have no ranks in Handle Animal, you can use a Charisma check to handle and push *domestic* animals, but you can’t teach, rear, or train animals. A druid or ranger with no ranks in Handle Animal can use a Charisma check to handle and push her animal companion, but she can’t teach, rear, or train other nondomestic animals.

Emphasis mine. One can push *only* domestic animals, nothing wild.

**If You Don't Buy This...**
If this *isn't* true, then any encounter with a creature possessing an Intelligence score of 1 or 2 can be obviated by making a Handle Animal skill check (DC 30). That's because "[y]ou can use this skill on a creature with an Intelligence score of 1 or 2 that is not an animal, but the DC of any such check increases by 5." A [bandersnatch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/bandersnatch), for example, is Int 2.

Comment: Good point, though part of me thought this would be a really neat way to use the skill but I guess it would make certain types of encounters obsolete.